# Searching jobs in London, ON shows only London, UK results

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I am trying to search for jobs in London, Ontario but I only see results for London, United Kingdom.

They are 5800km away!

Update: The question got 75 votes but there is not even a single solution. Any idea why it is happening? how to prevent it?

[image: Screenshot of search results for jobs in London, Ontario, showing only jobs in London, United Kingdom]

Comment: Only the last 20km is a though commute so I'm told ...

Comment: Well the swim's not so easy either.

Comment: Stop copying the names of the towns, last warning. At least some of your peers added "New" to the plagiarized names!

Comment: If only John Graves Simcoe could have foreseen the havoc his chauvinism would wreak on future job searches... At least Toronto isn't York anymore, that's *something*.

Comment: I hope you like curry, kebabs and warm beer...

Comment: @MartinJames: "Warm beer" like Cobra served at 11º?

Comment: @AnderBiguri As I point out many times, we didn't plaigarise, the British repeated themselves. It was British people who copied their own names. It was named by an Englishmen who was born and died in England, and by no means a Canadian.

Comment: @ArtB I was, certainly, joking ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I cannot comment.  What happens in the Indian, stays in the Indian:)

Comment: Try to remove the comma after London. the suggestions does contain 'London ON, Canada' (and seems to work)

Comment: @Mixxiphoid The site suggest that style, I did not type it I selected it from suggested drop-down.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a new future-predicting feature. The search engine knows that you'll eventually end up in the UK and wants you to get the best job possible for your situation. Don't ask me how, only the code knows that.

Comment: @MartinJames if only that were true

Comment: @Arashsoft are you still experiencing this? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Des Yes I can. In Developer Jobs page, I type london in the location field and I select "London, On, Canada" from the suggested dropdown. All of the jobs are from London, UK. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-london-on?sort=i

Comment: @Des, I found an interesting behavior. If I refresh the page or click on the link, the job search works correctly (However it shows jobs in Toronto which is not in 20km range but it is better). But when I select it from dropdown it shows London, Uk jobs.

Comment: @Des The difference is when I select from the suggested dropdown, the url becomes like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=London%2C+ON%2C+Canada&d=20&u=Km` Refreshing the page change the url to `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-in-london-on?sort=i`

Comment: @Arashsoft the url on refresh is intended behavior. The first url you linked doesn't return any London, UK jobs for me. I've asked my team and no one else can reproduce this either. Mind clearing your cache and seeing if that works?

Comment: @Des, Did you try to reproduce the issue with steps I provided? I cleared cache and still it happens. `In Developer Jobs page, I type london in the location field and I select "London, On, Canada" from the suggested dropdown`

Comment: @Arashsoft yes, initially I did follow your steps and could not reproduce the issue. However when I mimic an IP in London, ON, I am able to reproduce this. I'm passing this back to the team again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize for taking this long to fix it.

It appears it was a caching issue, which should now be fixed - please let us know if you see incorrect results again.

Comment: I confirm it is fixed now :)  I like the message `This isn't exactly what you searched for, but you might be interested in these jobs:`. So I can distinguish exact searches and suggestions. Thanks